# How to let user login to SPA application using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I wrote an aws cli command which gets responses successfully.
I am trying to write an equivalent code using AWS SDK java. But I can't.
I test the java project on a local machine and will deploy it to cloud as an SPA application for browsers.

---

Here follows the aws cli command.

```
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth \
  --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \
  --client-id 1e18esapaevuae9evrtcqmhntp \
  --auth-parameters USERNAME="user1",PASSWORD="pwd12345" \
  --region ap-northeast-1
```

---

And here follows the java code which gets runtime errors saying "Access key must be specified".
Please help me on how to fix this java code. Or am I in a wrong or unusual direction?

```
 package org.acme;

import java.util.Map;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.*;

public class App {
   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java App <password>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Replace with your actual AWS Region
        Region region = Region.AP_NORTHEAST_1;

        // Replace with your actual Cognito User Pool client ID
        String clientId = "1e18esapaevuqx9evrtcqmhntp";

        // Replace with your actual Cognito User Pool ID
        String userPoolId = "your-user-pool-id";

        // Replace with the username
        String username = "user1";

        // Password provided as a command-line argument
        String password = args[0];

        // Create a Cognito Identity Provider client
        CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        // Initiate authentication using USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow
        InitiateAuthResponse initiateAuthResponse = cognitoClient.initiateAuth(InitiateAuthRequest.builder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .authFlow(AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)
                .authParameters(
                        Map.of(
                                "USERNAME", username,
                                "PASSWORD", password
                        )
                )
                .build());

        // Extract the session token and other relevant information from the response
        AuthenticationResultType authenticationResult = initiateAuthResponse.authenticationResult();

        // Process the authentication result as needed
        System.out.println("Authentication successful");
        System.out.println("Access Token: " + authenticationResult.accessToken());
        System.out.println("ID Token: " + authenticationResult.idToken());
        System.out.println("Refresh Token: " + authenticationResult.refreshToken());
        System.out.println("Expires In: " + authenticationResult.expiresIn());
    }
}
```

If you have how to fix the java code, please give me it.

Or if my direction is wrong or unusual please give me the standard one.

Edit: In aws console, I have chosen to not create credential for the client application.

Edit: I understand  I should not hardcode any access key. But I am not sure. Please consult me.

Thank you in advance.